# Simplify repeating attributes across elements

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I'm new to **React** with **react-bootstrap** and what I'd like to achieve seems trivial, but didn't found the answer. Either I didn't have the correct search query or, it's simply not possible.
I have multiple elements which share the same attributes

```
<Form>
  <Form.Control size="sm" plaintext={!editable} readOnly={!editable} value={title} />
  <Form.Control size="sm" plaintext={!editable} readOnly={!editable} value={desc} />
  <Form.Control size="sm" plaintext={!editable} readOnly={!editable} value={qtty} />
  <Form.Control size="sm" plaintext={!editable} readOnly={!editable} value={year} />
</Form>
```

Question:
Is it possible to simplify with something like

```
const conf= `size="sm" plaintext=$(!editable) readOnly=$(editable)` // whatever the formatting

<Form>
  <Form.Control {conf} value={title} />
  <Form.Control {conf} value={desc} />
  <Form.Control {conf} value={qtty} />
  <Form.Control {conf} value={year} />
</Form>
```

Thanks for your Help

Comment: You can use a reducer or a state object

Comment: Your `conf` variable has to be an object (`{size: 'sm', plaintext: !editable, readonly: editable}`) and you pass that to `<Form.Control />` component using [spread syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) (`<Form.Control {...conf} value={title} />`)

Answer (score 1):

This is what React is built for!  You can easily make a `FormControl` component and simply pass in the different variables via props.  It may look like this:

```
export default function FormControl(props) {

      const conf = {size: 'sm', plaintext: !editable, readonly: editable}

      return(
        <Form.Control {...conf} value= 
        {props.value} />
      )
}
```

Import the new `FormControl` component into your parent form page and it will end up looking like this:

```
<Form>
  <FormControl value={title} />
  <FormControl value={desc} />
  <FormControl value={qtty} />
  <FormControl value={year} />
</Form>
```

And if you want to really make it look decent, simply store all your values in an array and map over them into your new `FormControl` component:

```
<Form>
   {values.map(value => {
     <FormControl value={value} />
   })}
</Form>
```

If you need to change the style like `size` or `plaintext`, you can easily associate changes from the parent down to the `FormControl` component via `props` (just like we did with `value`).

Comment: Wrapping native `<Form.Control />` component into extra layer (custom `<ForrmControl />` component) might be a bad idea from performance standpoint. It doesn't stack up quite well with ["composition over inheritance"](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) principle either. You might also want to pass a `key` prop inside a `map()` loop.

Comment: You think so?  I've rarely used react-bootstrap but the docs highlight a couple of use-cases where it appears they decoupled ````<Form.Control />```` in some form of isolated component.  Here is a link of them doing a custom ````InputReadOnlyExample````: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/form-control/.  You may be right though and of course, you ALWAYS want to pass a ````key```` prop, but I just forgot to do it in my example.